# Такая проблема не знаю как создать файл по имеющемуся пути , нужна помощь

Tags: java, android, файлы, try-catch

Я получаю путь к файлу через этот участок кода, а потом отправляю его в виде строки на другую активность
и там уже пытаюсь получить доступ к файлу через второй участок кода , других способов не нашел ,но он не работает ,может кто поможет. Буду очень благодарен.

```
private void getFile() {
    Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    chooseFile.setType("*/*");
    chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
    startActivityForResult(chooseFile, 3);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 3 && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            src = data.getData().getPath();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), src, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

//Второй участок кода



try {
    file = new File(intent.getStringExtra("file"));
    FictionBook fb2 = new FictionBook(file);
    tv.setText(fb2.getAuthors().toString());
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
        if (file.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "файл есть", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "директория есть " + file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы прописали разрешение на создание файла в манефесте?

Comment: Да , написал. Вот так  <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Не работать можно по-разному. Чего вы ожидаете (в названии - создание файла, а в вопросе - получение пути до файла) и что происходит (я имею в виду по крайней мере то, какие всплывающие сообщения `Toast` появляются)?

Comment: Тост выдает директория есть + в консоли пишет , No such file or directory . Но файл должен быть если я путь правильно беру.

Comment: Так я и думал. У вас выражение `else` относится не к тому `if`, где вы проверяете, является ли указанный файл папкой, а к тому, где вы проверяете, существует ли файл. Таком образом ваше всплывающее сообщение указывает на то, что файл не существует

Comment: Ну я так и хотел сделать , если сообщение вывелось "директория есть ", значит он все таки прошел первый if и она есть , а потом пошел во второй if и если он его запорол, то я знаю,что это директория ,а не файл. Только я спрашивал как это исправить и не думаю,что перестановка if что-то исправит, файл не находится в любом случае.

Comment: Видимо, вы не смогли полностью реализовать свои намерения, поскольку, во-первых, блок, который выводит всплывающее сообщение, выполняется только тогда, когда файл - НЕ папка (довольно абсурдно ожидать в этом блоке, даже после проваленной проверки, того, что этот файл - папка), во-вторых, [`exists()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#exists()) проверяет существование как отдельного файла, так и папки, а значит, "директории нет"

Comment: Нашёл решение проблемы , оказывается , что путь верный , просто таким способом можно читать только медиаконтент , у меня нет доступа к файлам. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage